# Why are all doubles from Unity3d stored in "Firebase Database" rounded to 4 decimal places?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, double

When I try save double from Unity3d Editor in "Firebase Database" it always rounded to 4 decimal places. I need to save it with at least 8 decimal places. I don't have any problems with doubles when I save it to firebase from JS or GO, but when I do it from Unity it always rounded in DB.

I try to save double as part of object with *SetRawJsonValueAsync*, as part of experiment I try to save separate double with *SetValueAsync*. It doesn't metter.

```cpp
public class StructureBinding
{
    public string Id;
    //...
    double X;
    double Y;
}

public void Save()
{
    var sb = new StructureBinding
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        X = 55.7389229831519,
        Y = 37.633679
    }
    //save as object
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                  .GetReference(sb.Id)
                  .SetRawJsonValueAsync(sb);
    //save as double
    double testDouble = 55.7389229831519;
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                  .GetReference("testDouble")
                  .SetValueAsync(testDouble);
}
```

I expect that after reading that values from DB I will get X = 55.7389229831519, but it always X = 55.7389.
Also, I want to see correct values in firebase console, but in console I see values with 4 decimal digit. On the other hand, the values created from JS are displayed with the required number of digits.

UPDATE:
Problem exists only in Editor. On Device (iOs) the problem does not repeat.

Comment: It is most likely stored properly but the ToString only prints up to 4 digit. Try with ToString("N8");

Comment: @Everts I thought that this is just a feature of displaying values. But I looked at the values in the debugger and see that they are read from the database already rounded. At the same time, the values that are saved from JS to Unity are read correctly (without rounding). Based on this, I concluded that the problem is in the Firebase Database library, which I use in Unity to save values.

Comment: I found that problem exists only in Editor. On Device (iOs) double saving without rounding.